# How can I use LaunchEffect in the AndroidView in the Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use a LaunchEffect to the AndroidView for collecting data from the ViewModel Stateflow but I get an error. how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: The factory parameter of an AndroidView is not a composable. It is used to return a view based object. You can't use LaunchedEffect inside an AndroidView. You can only use it inside a composable.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodels-source-of-truth

Answer (score 0):

You can run the LaunchedEffect only inside a `@Composable` function, this means that your lamba should me annotated with `@Composable () -> Unit` in order to be compatibile. But I'm not pretty sure that is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use composable LaunchedEffect not inside composable scope.
Move launched effect outside of getMapAsync.

You can do something like.

```
@Composable
fun MapViewContainer {
   ...

   var mapIsReady by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

   ...

    mapView.getMapAsync {
       mapIsReady = true
       ...
    }

    ...

    if (mapIsReady) {
       // do some compose things
    }
  }
}
```